# Messing with signals, pipes and forks in C

Tags: c, bash, shell, signals, fork

How can I get the a process to listen for user input without terminating? . So, for example, i want the bash to wait for X minutes, and if i say "stop" it quits, or else just keeps waiting... How can I achieve that? So, upon execution my process would wait , and then I want to be able to stop, pause or continue through stdin, typing "stop", "continue" or "pause. Thank you.

Comment: Why can't you use a read function like fgets in a loop?

Comment: OK, so "stop" and Ctrl-C should make the program exit. And what exactly are "pause" and "continue" supposed to do?

Comment: Please reread your question because you are stating conflicting requirements.

Comment: @Mabus Forget the ctrl+c, the idea is to have a counter, and the counter should stop if i type "pause" and continue if i type "continue". This must be achieved through signals, execs,forks...

Comment: If something has to keep going while you are waiting for user input, you need threads. One thread has to wait for user input (like in @chatraed's answer) and the other one has to do the counting.

Comment: Do you want to update your counter using a timer or in a loop?

Comment: @Mabus When the main process starts, i need to start a global counter, and control it through commands,  which act through signals, with signal(SIGALRM, alarmHANDLER, thats what i dont know :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple (but wasteful) option is that the initial program forks and then wait for input. The child process can update the counter.

When the parent program receive "pause" it sends the signal SIGTSTP to the child.

When the parent program receive "continue" it sends the signal SIGCONT to the child.

When the parent program receive "stop" it sends the signal SIGQUIT to the child.

If you want, you can also set a SIGINT handler in the parent using sigaction that kills the child when you type Ctrl+C.

Answer (score 1):

C piece of code, responsible of reading the user actions (*TESTED*):

```
int main()
{
    /* start function */
    char choice;
    while(1)
    {
        printf("Enter s (stop), c (continue) or p (pause): ");
        scanf("%c",&choice);
        /* protect against \n and strings */
        while(choice != '\n' && getchar() != '\n'); 

        switch(choice) {
            case 's' :
                printf("Stop!\n" );
                /* stop function */
                return 0;
            break;
            case 'c' :
                printf("Go on!\n" );
                /* resume function */
            break;
            case 'p' :
                printf("Pause!\n" );
                /* pause function */
            break;
            default :
                printf("What?\n" );
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot !!! This helps a lot man, now i just need to know how to , upon receiving a command (e.g. "pause") pause the process or send a signal to stop the global counter to keep counting.